# NFT's environmental/computational cost breakdown?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, tokens, nft

I've read the NFT and mining documentation on the Ethereum website, and I can't wrap my head around two things.

1. If NFT's are not equivalent to Ethereum coins and therefore do not require solving hash problems to generate, where does the energy consumption required to generate them come from?
2. Once NFT's are on the blockchain, how is the energy consumption (or gas) needed to verify them used?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Computation performed in the EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) is repeated across all miners. Then, the miners all solve those hash functions in order to see who 'wins' the credit for mining that set of transactions.

AFAIK the gas consumption is needed to put the NFT on the blockchain. Once it's there, you don't have to pay any gas to confirm it. The completed transactions are public, so everyone can see them.